# Securing an android smartphone

Tags: encryption, android, backup

Recently I got a new smartphone (OnePlus 6T, Android 9 Pie) and would like to do everything right from the start.

My main concerns are, I would like to be able to backup my data, I would like the data to be encrypted and not to be accessed, finding it, when lost, would be good as well.

I take it, that in the last years a lot changed, many things are implemented in Android already. So it's not really so that one has to check out many app solutions.

Finding the smartphone, letting it ring or wipe can be done through android.com/find.

I guess apps for securing against wlan fakes and so on is not needed anymore? So faking wlan-names and more. I have the virustotal app installed, I guess that's fine for a virusscanner, wouldn't go with strange apps anyway.

Encryption, I read android is encrypted by default, who can still access the data without knowing my unlock pattern?

Thinking over it, fingerprint or face might be really unsafe. Shouldn't a fingerprint taken from a glass or a foto of my face be enough already to break this? Would be still enough security for a lost smartphone, however how far of a threat goes someone with smartphone repair shop knowledge and internet access.

Also, regarding encryption, let's say I don't want to risk family peace for some more private wife fotos leaked. Is there a way to properly encrypt them on a second level? I have read most of these image secure apps are nothing more like fakes. They only restrict access in stupid and useless ways.

Also, when opening such fotos, how to avoid them being saved somewhere in the cloud or lying around in tempfolders for some time?

Which leads me to the last point. Backups. I have read there is a function to secure the smartphone to google drive. Is the data encrypted on google drive?

Also, it only backs up some things. How to back up everything, that can be backed up without rooting?

I wouldn't feel good about it having the data unencrypted in a google drive folder. Also I don't want to have a bad surprise by finding that not everything was backed up at the end.

The images have another option Backup and sync, but the images are stored without encryption, which isn't ok for me.

So how safe are these inbuilt options and how to ensure having everything possible saved? Surely 2FA-Keys won't be backed up, but files I put down in the rootfolder of the filesystem should not be gone after my phone does not live anymore.

Sorry about the long text, just want to make it right this time.

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian

Comment: Hi there - unfortunately your post is waaay too broad, with various unrelated questions in it. Please look at other questions we have here and our [ask] page for guidance.